# Normalizr and recursive nested structure

Tags: redux, normalizr

I'm using normalizr to flatten a structure like the following one:

```
{
  "fields":[{
    "id":"29",
    "text": "something"
  }, {
    "id":"16",
    "text": "something"
    "fields":[{
      "id":"17",
      "text": "something"
    }]
  }, {
    "id":"18",
    "text": "something"
  }
}
```

My structure has an array of **fields** and a **field** may also have nested fields. There's only **one level of nesting allowed**.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
const block = new schema.Entity('fields')
const blockList = new schema.Array(block)

block.define({
  fields: blockList
})

const normalizedData = normalize(originalData, blockList)
```

After running this snippet, normalizedData has a **results** property and it only has the first level of field ids, even though **entities** has all the fields normalized, including the nested ones.

[image: result of normalize]

I'd like to have in the **results** array all the ids, including the nested ones. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to have in the results array all the ids, including the nested ones. What am I missing?

This is how Normalizr works. The returned `result` is always in the same format of the input data. You won't be able to get what you are asking for from Normalizr.

If, however, you're just looking for a list of `blocks`, pull that from the `entities`:

```
const blockIds = Object.keys(normalizedData.entities.blocks);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a `normalized form` for your data structure in redux.
This is advisable if your application need growth in complexity.

There is an interesting article on redux docs.
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

A normalized form take some ideas from db counterpart and `Normalizr` works in that way, so your request does not really match with how `Normalizr` works.

Please consider @Paul Armstrong answer for a work around if you really need get `blocks` in that way.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your point... that's exactly why I'm trying to use Normalizr for: to normalize the data I'm getting from an external source before creating my store with the state shape already normalized (with Normalizr)